# Eclipse reports web.xml file does not exist, even though it does exist

Tags: gwt, war, google-eclipse-plugin, web-inf

I have a GWT project. I have the web.xml created and placed in webapp/WEB-INF, war/WEB-INF as well as war/. But Eclipse keeps throwing me the error that

```
The web.xml file does not exist
```

When I right click on the error and look into Properties, I see this entry

```
In folder: <myproject>/war
```

Though I have the file placed there, why does Eclipse keep reporting that error?

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: Is it a MAVEN project?

Comment: Please share the project structure.

Comment: Do you have both `webapp` as well as `war` folder? Its not correct.

Comment: `web.xml` must be placed under WEB-INF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please validate

Go To

```
Project -> Properties -> Google -> Web Application -> WAR directory
```

[image]

GWT Project structure

[image]

Comment: I've run into this issue before, and this worked for me.

Comment: @Braj I have the War folder, but am still getting the error. I dont see any images to the post. Can you reload the images please.

Comment: @Jess URL of the attached images in the post. Please let me know if it still there is an issue to open it. http://i.stack.imgur.com/mUvju.png and http://i.stack.imgur.com/cOZ8T.png